# Escape flights and insights

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> The first is a story that makes you hold on tight.
>   The second's returning with colours that aren't bright.
>   The third is a part that's reflecting no sunlight.
>   The fourth is an animal's Hadean escape flight.
>   The fifth one might offer unverified insight.
>   So tell me, can you guess all five of our names right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These sound like:

> a list of the top five best selling albums of all time.

The first is a story that makes you hold on tight.

> Thriller - Michael Jackson

The second's returning with colours that aren't bright.

> Back in Black - AC/DC

The third is a part that's reflecting no sunlight.

> The Dark Side of the moon - Pink Floyd

The fourth is an animal's Hadean escape flight.

> Bat Out of Hell

The fifth one might offer unverified insight.

> Rumours - Fleetwod Mac

As a matter of record

> [List of best-selling albums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_albums) not counting Greatest Hits/Various artists

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer**
I don't really see any correlation between the lines but I believe:

The First:

> This is an Epic.

The Second:

> Colors that aren't bright are Dull.

The Third:

> When something reflects no sunlight, you could call it Opaque or Black.

The Fourth:

> No idea here

The Fifth:

> Unverified insight could be called a Guess